# how to count distinct values in Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

json file

```
{"people":[{"Name":"Ray Parker","Email":"luctus.et.ultrices@natoque.ca","State":"Wyoming","Country":"Tuvalu","Martial Status":"Divorced","Department Name":"Tech Support","Company Name":"Borland","Title":"Dr.","Gender":"Male"},
{"Name":"Davis Hooper","Email":"et.libero.Proin@egetvarius.org","State":"Nunavut","Country":"Bangladesh","Martial Status":"Divorced","Department Name":"Public Relations","Company Name":"Cakewalk","Title":"Mr.","Gender":"Female"}, ...... and so on
```

I like to make a json object from this with the distinct values of Country and the count of people in that country.

I tried the code

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    var data = $.ajax({
        url: "Data_prop.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var unique = {};
    var param = "Country"
    $.each(data.people, function() {
        if (!unique[this[param]])
            unique[this[param]] = [];   
        unique[this[param]].push(this);
    });

    for(var d in unique) {
      alert(d);
    }

        });
```

The error i got in console

```
TypeError: a is undefined
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
Line 2
```

Does any have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I dont think you can `push()` values on to an object. Its ment to be used on arrays.

Comment: There is error in your jquery library include by you. Please replace the library with any other.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha i use the cdn <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SreekeshOkky : The error you got in console is due to the library include by you. replace the library with : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

And try then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function(data)
{
    var variables = {};
    var param = "Country"
    $.each(data.people, function()
    {
        if (!variables[this[param]])
            variables[this[param]] = [];    
        variables[this[param]].push(this);
    });

    for(var d in variables) {
        // add d to array here
        // or do something with d
        // variables[d] is the array of people
    }
}
```